# Which URL path that would result in a call to getName()?

Tags: soa, restful-url

I have a restful web service that looks like :

```
@path("/resource")
Class HelloWorld {
 @path("/id")
 @Get
 public String getName() {
 return "a name";
 }
}
```

Which of URLs path that would result in a call to getName()  ?

1. resource/id or
2. resource/id/name

Answer (score 0):

To call `getName()` you have to do a `GET` request on `/resource/id`.